# heat map and dark theme: google maps vs mapbox

Tags: android, google-maps, mapbox, heatmap

I want to develop a map in my android app using a theme similar to the dark theme of mapbox and i want to use a heat map too. I'm thinking about three solutions, but all of them have problems

1° solution: Use the native google maps and their  support for heat maps. The problem here is that there is nothing about styled themes for MapFragments similar the Mapbox dark theme.

2° solution: Use the native MapView by MapBox aar. The problem here is that i know nothing about support heat maps from the MapBox Android SDK.

3° solution: Use a UrlTileProvider to load a custom tile and put it over the native Google Maps and use the native heat map support over the mapbox tile. The problem here is that the tile is very ugly when I load it from an url, because text and images are pixelated.

Maybe i'm doing anything wrong in one of (or all) this solutions. There is a better idea to do what i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question using Google Maps and loading my Mapbox theme through [custom UrlTileProvider](https://github.com/cocoahero/android-gmaps-addons/blob/master/src/com/cocoahero/android/gmaps/addons/mapbox/MapBoxOnlineTileProvider.java) available on Github. This use case is the third one solution described in my question, so how i said above, using this solution I'm loading a low quality Tile with pixelated images and texts.

To solve this problem, i had to spend a lot of time reading the MapBox documentation and I discovered that is possible to load the tile with 2x resolution (described [here](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/maps/)) to images.

Basically, to load a MapBox the 2x resolution and get the advantages of Google Maps functionality, we should to:

Chage

```
{http or https}://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{map id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

to

```
https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{map id}/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token={your access token}
```

Obviously you should to change the getTileUrl method because of String.format used here.

So basically to load a MapBox tile with good resolution and get the advantages of Google Maps functionallity, we need to use the v4 mapbox webservices and setting the content format to @2x.png